# Overriding property type (class) with other type (class that is extending the first one) in PHP7

Tags: php, types, properties, extends

So, I have defined some data structures as php classes with properties only (similar syntax to C/C++ struct).
To be type strict in an easy way and have properties common for all the structures in one place - I figured out to define first basic structure as abstract class - it should never be instantiated, and all the "really used" structures will be extending it. Working example:

```
// Parent struct def: Common data for all the shapes, not meant to be instantiated
abstract class Shape {
    public int $posX, $posY;
    public string $color;
}

// Real structure def: I would like to use this one in code a real structure
class Rectangle extends Shape {
    public int $width, $height;
}
```

Then, I tried to define classes for working with these structures. Concept was very similar: basic abstract class with features common for all the structures, and one child class extending it for each structure. Continuing previous working example:

```
abstract class ShapeRenderer {
    public Shape $shapeData;

    public function SetShapeData(Shape $shapeData) {
        $this->shapeData = $shapeData;
    }
}

class RectangleRenderer extends ShapeRenderer {
    public Rectangle $shapeData; // fatal error line

    public function SetShapeData(Rectangle $shapeData) { // warning here
        $this->shapeData = $shapeData;
    }
}

// init these variables for some testing after
$rect = new Rectangle();
$rect->width = 10;

$render = new RectangleRenderer();
$render->SetShapeData($rect);
```

Sadly, I cannot override type of inherited property $shapeData from abstract *Shape* to real one which is extending it - *Rectangle* (line with comment "fatal error line") gives:

```
Fatal error: Type of RectangleRenderer::$shapeData must be Shape (as in class ShapeRenderer)
```

So I commented that line. Still same error was happing when I did override param type from *Shape* to more strict *Rectangle* in *ShapeRenderer* method *SetShapeData*. Changing parent method to abstract one without a body in *ShapeRenderer* resulted in exchanging fatal error for a warning:

```
Warning: Declaration of RectangleRenderer::SetShapeData(Rectangle $shapeData) should be compatible with ShapeRenderer::SetShapeData(Shape $shapeData)
```

The code seems to be working, I can access *$render->shapeData->width* dirrectly just fine, but when i try to var_dump whole *$render->shapeData* it says that it's of type *Shape* and doesn't have property *width*. So it's clearly not the good solution

Is there any way to handle it other than:

> declare property $shapeData without specyfing its type, only once - in common abstract class *ShapeRenderer*
> remove declaration of $shapeData in common abstract class *ShapeRenderer* (+ all code accessing it there), and declare it only in every child class (using any type)
> ?
> Both ways doesn't sound right to me